# How to determine what to scroll the body or html use vinilla.js when writing the scroll function scrollTop

Tags: javascript

How to determine what to scroll the body or html use vinilla.js (native js), how to do it with jquery understandable, but I would like to find a solution using only vanilla.js.
I did so:

```
elem=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement:document.body,
from=elem.scrollTop
```

Everything works there elem.scrollTop !== 0 , but if not then

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop==document.documentElemen==0
```

And I create the scrollTo function on vinilla.js and need to know what to assign 
elem.scrollTop=from+....;
I just write the function scrollTo and if elem.scrollTop == 0 then the function works correctly.
Here is an example of the function:

```
var scrollBlock,wh,windowScroll;
wh=window.innerHeight;
var element=document.getElementById('to-top');
windowScroll=function(){
    var elem=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement:document.body,from=elem.scrollTop;
    if(from<=50){
        element.classList.add('no-visible');
    }else{
        element.classList.remove('no-visible');
    }
};
windowScroll();
window.addEventListener("scroll",windowScroll,false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var scrollBlock,wh,windowScroll;
wh=window.innerHeight;
var element=document.getElementById('to-top');
windowScroll=function(){
    var elem=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement:document.body,from=elem.scrollTop;
    if(from<=50){
        element.classList.add('no-visible');
    }else{
        element.classList.remove('no-visible');
    }
};
windowScroll();
window.addEventListener("scroll",windowScroll,false);


function scrollTo(Y,duration,easingFunction,callback){
    //var scrollY=window.pageYOffset?window.pageYOffset:document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop;
    //console.log(scrollY);
    console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
    var start=Date.now(),
        elem=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement:document.body,
        from=elem.scrollTop,
        easingFunction=easingFunction||easing.linear;
    if(from===Y){
        if(typeof callback=='function') callback();
        return;
        /* Prevent scrolling to the Y point if already there */
    }
    function min(a,b){
        return a<b?a:b;
    }

    function scroll(timestamp){
        var currentTime=Date.now(),
            time=min(1,((currentTime-start)/duration)),
            easedT=easingFunction(time);
        elem.scrollTop=(easedT*(Y-from))+from;
        if(time<1) requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
        else if(typeof callback=='function') callback();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(scroll)
}

var easing={
    // no easing, no acceleration
    linear:function(t){
        return t
    },
    // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuad:function(t){
        return t*t
    },
    // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuad:function(t){
        return t*(2-t)
    },
    // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuad:function(t){
        return t<.5?2*t*t:-1+(4-2*t)*t
    },
    // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInCubic:function(t){
        return t*t*t
    },
    // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutCubic:function(t){
        return (--t)*t*t+1
    },
    // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutCubic:function(t){
        return t<.5?4*t*t*t:(t-1)*(2*t-2)*(2*t-2)+1
    },
    // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuart:function(t){
        return t*t*t*t
    },
    // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuart:function(t){
        return 1-(--t)*t*t*t
    },
    // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuart:function(t){
        return t<.5?8*t*t*t*t:1-8*(--t)*t*t*t
    },
    // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuint:function(t){
        return t*t*t*t*t
    },
    // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuint:function(t){
        return 1+(--t)*t*t*t*t
    },
    // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuint:function(t){
        return t<.5?16*t*t*t*t*t:1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t
    }
};
var smoothScroll=function(){
    scrollTo(500,700,easing.easeOutQuad);
};
document.getElementById('to-top').addEventListener('click',smoothScroll,false);
```